# AutoHotkey - How to make background clicking without activate the window?

Tags: background, autohotkey, clicking

I has some code as below

```
    DetectHiddenWindows On
SetControlDelay -1
WinHide, Form1

Loop
{
sleep, 1000
ControlClick, x1700 y160, Form1
}

^p:: Pause
^o:: WinShow, Form1
```

I expect this will bring me keep on clicking Form1 at background without activate the Form1 window, but it could only work when I activate it, once i Minimize it, it never click at all... Could someone professional help me on this??????

Comment: Try using the Client coordinates (not the Relative ones) shown by Windows Spy.

Comment: i did already try with 3 coordinates as well (absolute, relative, client).. but it still the same things :(

Comment: Add `pos` option as per [the documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm): `ControlClick, x1700 y160, Form1,,,, Pos`.